# For with present perfect and past simple

Tags: grammar

I can't understand why **for** can be used with ***past simple***. Here're two expressions from my textbook:

> How long have you been married?

meaning they're still married.

> How long were you married?

meaning they're no longer married.

For both of them the answers should be ***for 2 years***. What does ***for*** mean in both cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Q: How long have you been married?  A: Five happy years. Twenty total.

Comment: Does your answer mean till now?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't joke around like this in comments.  It means that I've been married a total of twenty years (from the wedding till now), but only five of those years have been happy.  Usually when people say I've been married for X happy years, they mean that they've been married for X years and they've all been happy years.  My wife doesn't think this is very funny either.

Comment: It's no problem with your joke:)Hope you're still happy:). I just try to catch the peculiarity  of present perfect usage with prepositions,adverbs.

Answer (score 1):

As a preposition, [***for***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for) can be used for:

> Indicating the length of (a period of time): *he was jailed for 12 years*, *I haven't seen him for some time*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Tense of a sentence doesn't have anything to do with its usage. For examples:

> I ran for 2 hours yesterday.

It indicates the length of running that happened yesterday.

> I will run for 2 hours this weekend.

It indicates the length of running that will happen this weekend.

> I have been running for 2 hours.

It indicates the length of running that started (around) 2 hours ago.

As you can see above, tense of a sentence has nothing to do with the preposition *for*'s usage.

Comment: You see in textbooks for is often explained as go together with present perfect. May be it is done to simplify the understanding for non-natives.

Comment: @Marita Yes, some grammar books emphasize that *for* is used with present perfect ***often***, but it doesn't necessarily mean it is used ***only*** with present perfect, i.e. "I had been drinking for an hour before he asked me to come back to office". It can be used with ***past perfect***, too.

Comment: Now I understand. I think I should ask one more question to clarify the usage of present perfect and past simple.

Comment: @Marita There are a lot of duplicates. I would advise you to use the search first before posting a question and ask a question based on how the previous answers don't answer your question. Your above question might be a duplicate (I couldn't find it), too.

Comment: Ok,I'll try to search the answer.